# How to return an array not an object with doctrine findOneBy method in symfony2?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have a situation in which I want to query the database with findOneBy($id) method from doctrine in symfony2.

```
$namePosting = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findOneById($userPosting);
```

The result it's an object with protected properties. I want to return it directly an array. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`findOneBy(array())` will always return null or object.

But you can use instead `findById($userPosting)` or `findBy(array('id' => $userPosting))` and it will return an array, e.g.:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findById($userPosting))
```

### Edited

Or you can add a method in `UserRepository` class:

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
    { 
        public function getUser($userPosting)
        {
           $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
             ->select('u')
             ->where('u =:userPosting')->setParameter('userPosting', $userPosting)
             ->getQuery()
             ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

           return $qb;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: well, yeah, the result it's stucked inside an array, but inside it is the same (an object with protected properties), look:

http://pastebin.com/MtrJgzJ9

How can I access the "firstname" for example ?

Comment: if you have $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findById($userPosting)); the firtsname will be $user->getFirstname(); (supposing you have a getter in user entity class named getFirstname()

Comment: That is perfect. You can access a property like this, BUT what if you want to return the whole object converted as an array ? Can you do that directly, or you need to use the serializer from symfony ?

Comment: You can create a custom query in your repository and call getResult(Querry::HYDRATE_ARRAY) on it. Please see my edited post.

Comment: You can use getOneOrNullResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY) instead of getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)