# Return array with Doctrine findBy method

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the Doctrine `findBy()` method, but I want to get arrays returned instead of objects. This is my query:

```
$results = $em
    ->getRepository('xBundle:x')
    ->findBy(
        array(),
        array('name' => 'ASC')
);
```

I did some research and found that `HYDRATE_ARRAY` is the way to do it, but I have no idea how to include that in the `findBy()` method.

**EDIT**
My query as it is, is returning objects. I don't want to create any methods in my repository; I want to just edit the existing query so that it returns arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return an array not an object with doctrine findOneBy method in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681567/how-to-return-an-array-not-an-object-with-doctrine-findoneby-method-in-symfony2)

Comment: you can not do it without creating method in repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910599/how-to-get-array-results-in-findall-doctrine

Comment: Why the explicit need for arrays instead of objects? Anyway, you can just cast objects to arrays (`$array = (array) $object;`) in php: [Link](https://3v4l.org/0MMXM). See the "Converting to Array" paragraph in the official [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side. This can result in some unexpected behaviour:*

Answer (score 2):

craete a function into repository and then create a query builder

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getArray()
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('x')
        ->orderBy('x.name', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

access to your function from controller

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xBundle:x')->getArray();
```

More info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)